# How to Run jar in Sequence inside Shell Script based on result?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Suppose I am 2 jar file and need to run them from shell script, i can use the below commands in the same script.

```
java -jar myApp1.jar

java -jar myApp2.jar
```

So it will start **myApp1.jar** first and then **myApp2.jar** file.

Question:
I want to run **myApp2.jar** *only if* the run of **myApp1.jar** is successful/completed. If myApp1.jar run is failed it will exit the shell script.

Can any one please help me how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java -jar myApp1.jar || exit 1 && java -jar myApp2.jar
```

Or

```
#!/bin/sh

if java -jar myApp1.jar; then
    echo 'myApp1.jar -- Successful!'
    if java -jar myApp2.jar; then
        echo 'myApp2.jar -- Successful!'
    else
        echo 'myApp2.jar -- Failed!'
        exit 1
   fi
else
    echo 'myApp1.jar -- Failed!'
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: My Complete script is something like below. But its not working. so some how I need to check if the myApp1.jar prcess completed.  Right now if it fails also, myApp2.jar will execute.


java -jar myApp1.jar

mkdir /xyz/myapp/data
if(condition){
   some logic on date
}
touch "appData2"
java -jar myApp2.jar